# Convert decimal to binary in python

Tags: python, binary, decimal

Is there any module or function in python I can use to convert a decimal number to its binary equivalent?
I am able to convert binary to decimal using int('[binary_value]',2), so any way to do the reverse without writing the code to do it myself?

Comment: Unlike the linked question "convert to binary string", I think this question is different. I came here looking to convert an integer to a corresponding binary *array* (or boolean array), and I think that would be a sensible answer.

Comment: @SanjayManohar   The pure string processing algorithm found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60693697/8929814) could be adapted to do what you want.

Answer (score 290):

all numbers are stored in binary. if you want a textual representation of a given number in binary, use `bin(i)`

```
>>> bin(10)
'0b1010'
>>> 0b1010
10
```

Comment: Misleading. bin() returns binary *string*, not binary

Comment: @hiperbolt could use a link to a non-misleading solution

Answer (score 86):

Without the 0b in front:

```
"{0:b}".format(int_value)
```

Starting with Python 3.6 you can also use [*formatted string literal* or *f-string*](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings), --- [PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/):

```
f"{int_value:b}"
```

Comment: I got the following error: `TypeError: non-empty format string passed to object.__format__`

Comment: same for me with python 3.5.2
TypeError: non-empty format string passed to object.__format__

ahh - now i got it, what you meant:
```>>> "{0:b}".format(47)
--->   '101111'

Comment: You also can determine amount of bits that it will be represented in this way:>>> `"{:0>15b}".format(3)` >>>
'000000000000011'

Comment: can also `format(int_value, 'b')`

Comment: the solution is incorrect with value < 0

Answer (score 84):

```
"{0:#b}".format(my_int)
```

Comment: Here's the format for printing with leading zero's: `"{0:08b}".format(my_int)`

Comment: @WaldoBronchart thats cool. Can you explain to me how does that work, having the leading zeros? Is that inbuilt, that you get the leading zeros with 0+8 or 0+16?

Answer (score 54):

```
def dec_to_bin(x):
    return int(bin(x)[2:])
```

It's that easy.

Comment: **-1** - don't return an int. Also, `dec_to_bin(-1)` gives `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'b1'`

Comment: can you explain that [2:] ?

Comment: Try `bin(2)`. You don't get '10'. You get '0b10'. Same possible pit with `hex(2)` ('0x2'). So you want all but the first two characters. So you take a slice that starts after the first two characters.

Comment: @zero_cool

if test_var  = "Hello world"
then test_var[2:] = "llo world"

Comment: @Eric could you explain why you shouldn't return an int??

Comment: @Wallace: because binary and decimal are a choice of how to _show_ the number, not part of the number itself. `dec_to_bin(0b101) == 101`, which is nonsense because none of operations you can apply to 101 have any relation to the original 5 - for instance,  `dec_to_bin(0b101) + 1 == 102`.

Comment: TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Answer (score 20):

You can also use a function from the numpy module

```
from numpy import binary_repr
```

which can also handle leading zeros:

```
Definition:     binary_repr(num, width=None)
Docstring:
    Return the binary representation of the input number as a string.

    This is equivalent to using base_repr with base 2, but about 25x
    faster.

    For negative numbers, if width is not given, a - sign is added to the
    front. If width is given, the two's complement of the number is
    returned, with respect to that width.
```

Answer (score 13):

I agree with @aaronasterling's answer. However, if you want a non-binary string that you can cast into an int, then you can use the canonical algorithm:

```
def decToBin(n):
    if n==0: return ''
    else:
        return decToBin(n/2) + str(n%2)
```

Comment: `int(bin(10), 2)` yields `10`. `int(decToBin(10))` yields `101` and `int(decToBin(10), 2)` yields 5. Also, your function hit's recursion limits with `from __future__ import division` or python 3

Comment: @aaron, the latter point can be solved by switching to `//` (truncating division); the former, by switching the order of the two strings being summed in the `return`. Not that recursion makes any sense here anyway (`bin(n)[2:]` -- or a `while` loop if you're stuck on some old version of Python -- will be _much_ better!).

Comment: This is awesome! it could go with the **lambda** way too :] 

`binary = lambda n: '' if n==0 else binary(n/2) + str(n%2)`

Comment: @AzizAlto I get a busload full of numbers with lots of `e-`, also in the recursive call dectobin.

Comment: @Timo lol apparently you are using Python3 just change `binary(n/2)` to `binary(n//2)` then you won't get that busload :-)

Comment: I think it is better to use `if n==0: return '0'` instead of `if n==0: return ''` since for n=0 your code return empty string which is incorrect answer. Although this approach gives you an extra 0 on left for non-zero inputs.

Answer (score 9):

```
n=int(input('please enter the no. in decimal format: '))
x=n
k=[]
while (n>0):
    a=int(float(n%2))
    k.append(a)
    n=(n-a)/2
k.append(0)
string=""
for j in k[::-1]:
    string=string+str(j)
print('The binary no. for %d is %s'%(x, string))
```

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of completion: if you want to convert fixed point representation to its binary equivalent you can perform the following operations:

1. Get the integer and fractional part.

   ```
   from decimal import *
   a = Decimal(3.625)
   a_split = (int(a//1),a%1)
   ```
2. Convert the fractional part in its binary representation. To achieve this multiply successively by 2.

   ```
   fr = a_split[1]
   str(int(fr*2)) + str(int(2*(fr*2)%1)) + ...
   ```

You can read the explanation [here](http://cs.furman.edu/digitaldomain/more/ch6/dec_frac_to_bin.htm).