# Python Decimal to Binary Array

Tags: python, binary, multidimensional-array

My question is related to this stackoverflow post: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528146/convert-decimal-to-binary-in-python), in which inspectorG4dget provided the code

```
def decToBin(n):
    if n==0: return ''
    else:
        return decToBin(n/2) + str(n%2)
```

which recursion Alex Martelli observed was unnecessary, since the obvious bin(x)[2:] could be used.  This is fine if the user needs the binary representation as a string.  However, I need the binary representation as a list or numpy ndarray.  As I can see, my options are a) adaptation of this code or b) something like this `string.split(','.join(bin(10)[2:]),',')`.  I know string operations tend to be expensive, but recursion can also be expensive.

Given that I need to convert an integer into an array_like of bits, which option (a or b) is likely to be more efficient?  Is there another simpler & better way completely?

Comment: this would work also: [c for c in bin(10)[2:]] or map(None, bin(10)[2:])

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply convert a string to list by `list()`.

```
list(bin(10)[2:])
```

Comment: Ah so simple.  Though I swear I tried that initially, and it gave me a list with 1 element ['1010'].  Now I'm ashamed to have this question even here :-).